# How to handle misspelled LUIS entity

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Lets suppose it is movie bot. I added entity MovieName, and phrase list containing movies. One of the movie name is "Star Wars", and if user misspell it to "Stra Wra" then how I can tackle this issue? Will Bing spell check service help for non English movie names, I'm not sure?

Answer (score 1):

LUIS will not be able to capture misspelled entities by itself unless you provide examples with misspelled entities which is not practical.

So you need to feed the utterances corrected to LUIS.

For Bing spelling correction service you have to try it yourself, but I guess it will handle your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you mean by "feed utterances corrected to luis"?

Comment: After you build the model and have the endpoint ready, so you want to send new queries to the endpoint, you will need to run a spell correction module before sending the queries to the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

If you expect some common misspellings that you expect to be repeated, you could add them in an exchangeable phrase list feature. That will help with the prediction of these misspelled entities.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this:

1. Use [synonyms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xzTu.png) with most common mistakes
2. Have another step in your pipeline (before going to LUIS), which matches user input to possible options and corrects them (even a self made solution would do great, but you can also try to add ElasticSearch with fuzzy queries)